# Android Network Stack

Tags: android, linux

I'm searching for information about "Security in Android Network Stack"? Does Android have the same network stack as in Linux 2.6?  If "No" then how much different is it from that of Linux 2.6???

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same stack.  Various vendor forks of Android may have some extra driver for their wireless chips, but besides that they use the same protocol implementations and mechanisms for networking.

Comment: Thanks for your breif answer, but whould you please tell me about some authentic resource of Android network Stack (i read somewhere that Android kernel is different from that of Linux with respect of TCP/IP stack)

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html it says it relies on Linux 2.6 for the network stack. I haven't seen any commits in the Android git tree that modifies the network stack, but you might also want to check it out, or even diff it with the Linux tree it was forked from.